# Problem in code of assigning method to JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am a beginner and covering a topic about "Defining methods in JavaScript Object" and I am stuck in this problem.

Here Jobleft is assigning whole function object to this.Serve instead of returning single value it returns whole function.

```js
  function person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.Serve = Jobleft;
  }

function Jobleft() {
  var service = 60 - this.age;
  return service;
}

var karl = new person("karl", 24);
var john = new person("john", 50);
document.write(karl.name + "You have " + karl.Serve + " years left");
document.write(john.name + "You have " + jhon.Serve + " years left");
```

```html
karlYou have function Jobleft(){ var service = 60 - this.age; return service; } years left
```

I expect output to be: karl you have 36 years left john you have 10 years left

Comment: You need to actually call the function: `"You have " + karl.Serve() + " years left"`

Answer (score 2):

Call the method, like this:

```
document.write(karl.name + "You have " + karl.Serve() + " years left");
```

Note the parens after `Serve`

```js
  function person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.Serve = Jobleft;
  }

function Jobleft() {
  var service = 60 - this.age;
  return service;
}

var karl = new person("karl", 24);
var john = new person("john", 50);
document.write(karl.name + "You have " + karl.Serve() + " years left");
document.write(john.name + "You have " + john.Serve() + " years left");
```